# How to display blank data in Thymeleaf in th:text

Tags: thymeleaf

I am trying to use Thymeleaf `if` and `unless` but it is not working. What I am trying to do is I want to check if the `statusNm` variable has a value of 'Approved' then it will display the content otherwise it will leave it blank.

But I am not able to achieve it. Please suggest me a solution.

```
<th>Approved Date</th>
<td th:if="${obj.statusNm}=='Approved'" th:text="${obj.modifyDt}"></td>
<td th:unless="${obj.statusNm}" th:text=""></td>
<th>Approved By</th>
<td th:if="${obj.statusNm}=='Approved'" th:text="${obj.modifier}"></td>
<td th:unless="${obj.statusNm}" th:text=""></td>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the alternative, you may look at [Conditional expressions](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#conditional-expressions) and evaluate your condition directly in `th:text` attribute ...

```
<th>Approved Date</th>
<td th:text="${obj.statusNm=='Approved'} ? ${obj.modifyDt}"></td>
<th>Approved By</th>
<td th:text="${obj.statusNm=='Approved'} ? ${obj.modifier}"></td>
```

Answer (score 1):

The equals check must be inside the curly brackets like this:

```html
<th>Approved Date</th>
<td th:if="${obj.statusNm=='Approved'}" th:text="${obj.modifyDt}"></td>
<td th:unless="${obj.statusNm=='Approved'}" th:text=""></td>
```